# Find roots for a function on a range

Tags: equation-solving

Assuming I have function `F[x_]:= (x-1)(x-2)(x-5)` and I want to find all roots on a range from $x=0$ up to $x=$3, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Reduce[(-5 + x) (-2 + x) (-1 + x) == 0 && 0 <= x <= 3, x]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
f[x_] := (x - 1) (x - 2) (x - 5)
```

Add the range as a constraint in [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) or [`NSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html)

```
soln1 = Solve[{f[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 3}, x]

(*  {{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}}  *)
```

Use [`ReplaceAll (/.)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) to get a list of the values

```
xVal = x /. soln1

(*  {1, 2}  *)

NSolve[{f[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 3}, x]

(*  {{x -> 1.}, {x -> 2.}}  *)
```

Comment: And also `NSolve[f[x]==0, x \[Element] Interval[{0,3}]]`, just to give one more way :-)

Comment: what about the brackets {} can i remove them ? also, can i stor the solved values in a list ??
Finally can i foe example tell mathematica that i need the first two roots with out knowing the range ?

Comment: for some reson the solve and Nsolve did not work, it tells me "Solve::eqf: x<=3 is not a well-formed equation."

Comment: @LoveEva - presumably you did not copy and paste the code above correctly; however, without showing your code I cannot guess. Whether you can get the first two roots without specifying a range (or even if `Solve` or `NSolve` can solve the equation) depends on the specific equation.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon

In[26]:= f[x_] := (x - 1) (x - 2) (x - 5)

soln1 = Solve[{f[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 3}, x]

During evaluation of In[26]:= Solve::eqf: x<=3 is not a well-formed equation. >>

Out[27]= Solve[{(-5 + x) (-2 + x) (-1 + x) == 0, 0 <= x <= 3}, x]

Comment: @LoveEva - copying from your comment works fine on my system. Try starting with a fresh kernel -- you may have some old definitions hanging around.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon it did not work, is it because im using mathematica 7?

Comment: @Bob Hanlon i just tried it with 9 it did work fine, so it is the difference in versions.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a difference between `NSolve[f[x] == 0 && 0 <= x <= 3, x]` and `NSolve[{f[x] == 0, 0 <= x <= 3}, x]`? In the present case, both work.

Comment: @anderstood - the documentation for `NSolve` states "NSolve[{Subscript[expr, 1], Subscript[expr, 2], ...}, vars] is equivalent to NSolve[Subscript[expr, 1]&&Subscript[expr, 2]&& ..., vars]. " Documentation for `Solve` has a similar statement.